# Retrofit query params

Tags: java, android, api, http, retrofit

I'm trying to configure a request to *http: //where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q(name_here);count=50?...*.
Not the best solution, I guess, but I tried

```
@GET("/v1/{location}")
Places getLocations(@Path("location") String locationName);
```

and pass there

```
getLocations("places.q(" + locationName + ");count=50");
```

But it still doesn't work as the string *();* is translated into *%28%29%3B*.

Can you suggest any solutions? It would be better to dinamycally modify only the *name_here* part, something like

```
@GET("/v1/places.q({location});count=50)
```

If it is not possible how do I have to pass symbols (); so that they are converted correctly?

Comment: Is there problem with *@GET("/v1/places.q({location});count=50") Places getLocations(@Path("location") String locationName);* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried

```
@GET("/v1/places.q({location});count=50") 
Places getLocations(@Path("location") String name)
```

a bit later and it works fine. I thought it will insert something like "/" or modify it, but it does exectly what I need.

Comment: Also worth noting that you can use `@EncodedPath` to skip the encoding of special characters.